Are Apple Airpods capable of producing 165 decibels of sound?
Inspired by this article, where a Texas family claim that an "Amber Alert" on their son's Airpods caused his eardrum to rupture.
https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-10830803/Boy-suffered-ruptured-ear-drum-hearing-loss-Apple-AirPods-blared-Amber-Alert.html
According to this, sound levels starting from 165 decibels would cause eardrum rupture:

When the loudness of a sound exceeds 165 dB, the pressure wave may
also rupture the tympanic membrane.

https://evidence.unboundmedicine.com/evidence/view/EBMG/457351/all/Acute_acoustic_trauma#:~:text=An%20intense%20sound%20wave%20will,also%20rupture%20the%20tympanic%20membrane.
Question: Are the Apple Airpods physically capable of producing 165 decibels of sound?

So what did your research show for the max power output of the Airpods?

Measuring the loudness of earbuds is actually quite difficult, because it depends heavily on the geometry of how it's inserted. I believe they actually use human shaped dummy ears for testing this.

I think we can agree that there is no practical reason to design the airpod to hit 165 dB, therefore Apple would be making design compromises to hit a target that is irrelevant. The main way to increase the SPL of a speaker of a given diameter is to make it move further, making the Airpod bigger and heavier. Alternatively make the speaker bigger in diameter, again making the Airpod bigger and heavier.  Does that sound likely?
165 dB is about 0.5 psi, the pressure increase you'd get from diving 3 ft below the surface while holding your breath. I doubt that would rupture a healthy eardrum, since I regularly duck dive down to 10-15 feet.

The short answer, "No."
But since this is the Engineering Stack Exchange, I'll give a more substantial answer.
A little research shows that Apple Airpods have a 0.093Wh battery and can play "up to" five hours.  Experience shows that if you play loud music, you get less life on the batteries. To make the numbers come out even, I'll say at high volume, you can get no more than 3.72 hours.  To consume a 0.093 Wh battery in 3.72 hours, the Airpods would be using 0.025 watts.
We find on the web that decibel measure is a logarithmic ratio of sound intensity, referenced to $10^{-12}$ $watts/meter^2$. (Technically, the logarithmic ratio times 10.) If all of the sound produced by a 100% efficient 0.025 watt amplifier went into a 1$cm^2$ ear canal, that would give a sound pressure level of:
$SPL= \frac{(0.025 watts)}{1 cm^2} X \frac{{(100cm)}^2}{1 meter^2}$
Simplifying,
$SPL=\frac{0.025 watts X 10^4 }{meter^2} $
for a sound pressure level of:
SPL=250 $\frac{watts}{meter^2}$
Finding 10 times the logarithmic ratio of $10^{-12}$ $\frac{watts}{meter^2}$ gives:
$dB=10*log(\frac{250}{10^{-12}})$
or:
$dB= 144$
Enough to damage your hearing very quickly but not up to the 160dB that the reference says is required to burst ear drums.
If you don't like those numbers, I'll produce some others.  Assuming we use up the entire 0.093 Wh battery in 0.93 hours (0:55:48) (to make the numbers come out even) that would mean the power is 0.1 watts.  Running the same calculations gives 1000 $\frac{watts}{meter^2}$ which gives 150 dB, still short of the 160 dB "required."
I don't doubt that Airpods can do a number on your hearing but I have trouble believing that the Airpods (from the article) "'ripped open' his eardrum."  I don't have Airpods but my earphones came with a warning about sound levels.  If you try hard enough, you can injure yourself with anything.  What's more, if you find the right lawyer, you can sue a big company for anything, as well.

I don't think this analysis can be trusted. There is no rule about manufacturer stated battery life that limits the maximum instantaneous power output. For example. Lets say a laptop has a stated battery life of 6 hours. How long do you think it will be if you blast the speakers, run CPU burn, and turn the monitor up to full brightness? I'm guessing somewhere around 30 minutes. But it could even be lower. As I said there are no rules about this.

@Drew, OK. I can deal with that.  How about if the entire battery is used up in 5 minutes and 34.8 seconds (0.093 hours)?  That would put the eardrum power at 160 dB, which is eardrum bursting power for my reference but not the 165 dB required by the OP.  I'm trying to attach an order of magnitude to a questionable assertion on the web.  The power of the Airpods is not published so we do the best we can. If we should ever get more conclusive numbers, my calculations will provide an upper bound.

It's not out of the question for a lipo to supply that kind of current or more. Tthat's only 60C, lipos up to 120C are common. And furthermore, the earbuds certainly contain some capacitance. Perhaps a glitch can cause the speaker armature to move violently once. The power required to do that is negligible, but it could still potentially break an eardrum.

It is possible to draw power from some batteries fast but the Airpod has been designed to provide power over a long time which is contrary to rapid power draw.  You are not getting massive power for a short time.  Plus, the amplifier has to deal with the power.  I'll continue to maintain that the answer is "No."  This is the type of question, if you ask three engineers, you'll get five answers.

It probably is a no, but I maintain that your analysis does not prove it. Ear buds are active devices and the "design" that limits the power draw can simply be that high power output is rarely used. There's no rule saying that high power output cannot be possible.

The speaker is a normal cone speaker. I don't know if the "cone" has the physical structure to run at those levels -- and the coil would certainly burn out quickly.  Also air becomes non-linear at high power densities, and friction losses become higher.  Even if the cone and coil didn't fail, output coupling will be reduced. Be fun to try it though.

@david Somebody was talking about what happens if you plug your stereo speakers into a 120VAC line?  The answer was a great loud noise that is the sound of the speaker self destructing.  I'm thinking this would be a similar case. I don't think the amplifier could put out enough power to put 160 dB into the ear but it would totally destroy the Airpod speaker trying.
